# How to check status of Spark applications using CLI or terminal?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We know we can check spark job status and other information using Spark Web UI.
But is there any way we can get the same kind of information using command line or terminal. For example if we can get the **submitted time**, **status** and **duration** of job.

I am writing an script to monitor and analyse the job for some purpose for that reason I want to capture these information by using commands.

I want more or less similar kind of output that we get using ***oozie job -info*** .

I have tried searching it but could not find any proper way to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this by spark REST API and **curl**, you can find all available endpoints [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html). Example output below.

```
$ curl http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   467  100   467    0     0  15064      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 29187[ {
  "id" : "local-1571419035658",
  "name" : "Spark shell",
  "attempts" : [ {
    "startTime" : "2019-10-18T17:17:14.124GMT",
    "endTime" : "1969-12-31T23:59:59.999GMT",
    "lastUpdated" : "2019-10-18T17:17:14.124GMT",
    "duration" : 0,
    "sparkUser" : "user123",
    "completed" : false,
    "appSparkVersion" : "2.4.0",
    "startTimeEpoch" : 1571419034124,
    "lastUpdatedEpoch" : 1571419034124,
    "endTimeEpoch" : -1
  } ]
} ]
```

and job details

```
$ curl http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/local-1571419035658/jobs/16
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   542  100   542    0     0  36133      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 36133{
  "jobId" : 16,
  "name" : "show at <console>:24",
  "submissionTime" : "2019-10-19T21:20:10.676GMT",
  "completionTime" : "2019-10-19T21:20:13.604GMT",
  "stageIds" : [ 30, 31, 32 ],
  "status" : "SUCCEEDED",
  "numTasks" : 202,
  "numActiveTasks" : 0,
  "numCompletedTasks" : 202,
  "numSkippedTasks" : 0,
  "numFailedTasks" : 0,
  "numKilledTasks" : 0,
  "numCompletedIndices" : 202,
  "numActiveStages" : 0,
  "numCompletedStages" : 3,
  "numSkippedStages" : 0,
  "numFailedStages" : 0,
  "killedTasksSummary" : { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the status of a Spark Application through the CLI using the below commands.

> YARN CLUSTER MANAGER

```
yarn application --status <application_id>
```

> MESOS/STANDALONE

```
spark-submit --status <application_id>
```